# Multiple Checkboxes in a Picture

Tags: php, html, css, checkbox

I know how to put a picture in one checkbox (via css)

But this example:

[image: checkboxes]

I want to put Checkboxes into the picture at every number exactly at this position. The checkboxes can also be next to the picture but at the exact positions.

How we do this ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to position a checkbox in an absolute position? You can use the `absolute` in css:

```css
div.container {
  position: relative;
}
.chk1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
}
.chk2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 65px;
  top: 65px;
}
.chk3 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 80px;
  top: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/aS3WP.jpg" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="chk1" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="chk2" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="chk3" />
</div>
```

You can change the `left` and `top` values to set them in the exact correct place you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.pic{
background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/aS3WP.jpg") no-repeat;
width:242px;
height:197px;
position: relative;
}
.poin1{
left: 165px;
bottom:50px;
position: absolute;
}
.poin2{
left: 165px;
bottom:90px;
position: absolute;
}
.poin3{
left: 155px;
bottom:125px;
position: absolute;
}
.poin4{
left: 180px;
bottom:122px;
position: absolute;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="pic">
<input type="checkbox" class="poin1">
<input type="checkbox" class="poin2">
<input type="checkbox" class="poin3">
<input type="checkbox" class="poin4">

</div>


</body>
</html>



    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">
    .pic{
    background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/aS3WP.jpg") no-repeat;
    width:242px;
    height:197px;
    position: relative;
    }
    .poin1{
    left: 165px;
    bottom:50px;
    position: absolute;
    }
    .poin2{
    left: 165px;
    bottom:90px;
    position: absolute;
    }
    .poin3{
    left: 155px;
    bottom:125px;
    position: absolute;
    }
    .poin4{
    left: 180px;
    bottom:122px;
    position: absolute;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="pic">
    <input type="checkbox" class="poin1">
    <input type="checkbox" class="poin2">
    <input type="checkbox" class="poin3">
    <input type="checkbox" class="poin4">

    </div>


    </body>
    </html>
```